# I want to groupby the data and then check a column to see if a string value is there, if it is keep the data otherwise drop the data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is an example. I want to group by student and check to see if class x is in the group by. If it is keep the data, otherwise remove the data

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `filter`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': [1, 1, 2, 2],
 'class': ['x', 'y', 'a', 'z'],
 'score': [100, 100, 50, 60]}
)

df.groupby('student').filter(lambda g: 'x' in g['class'].values)
```